# Python's type() function and its 'if' related problems

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-2.7

So I have the following code:

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter an integer, string or float:")
input_type = type(user_input)

if input_type == "str":
    print "Your string was %s." % user_input

elif input_type == "int":
    input_type = int(input_type)
    print "Your integer was %d." % user_input

elif input_type == "float":
    input_type = int(input_value)
    print "Your float was %d." % user_input

else:
    print "You did not enter an acceptable input."
```

This **does not** work — I believe because of the `if` — so I changed it to be:

```
if "str" in input_type
```

and `"int"` for the float and integer, but get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "types.py", line 4, in <module>
if "str" in input_type:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Why do I get this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

---

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter an integer, string or float:")
input_type = type(user_input)
```

Since `raw_input` always returns a string, `input_type` will always be `str` here.

---

```
if input_type == "str":
    print "Your string was %s." % user_input
```

`input_type` will be `str`—that is, the actual object representing the string type—not `"str"`, which is just a string. So, this will never be true, and neither will any of your other tests.

---

Changing this to:

```
if "str" in input_type:
```

… can't possibly help anything, unless you're expecting `input_type` to be either a collection of strings, or a longer string with `"str"` in the middle of it somewhere. And I can't imagine why you'd expect either.

---

These lines:

```
input_type = int(input_type)
```

… are trying to convert the `input_type`—which, remember, is a *type*, like `str` or `int`, not the value—to an integer. That can't be what you want.

---

These lines:

```
print "Your integer was %d." % user_input
```

Are printing the original string you received from the user, not the thing you converted to an `int`. This would work if you used `%s` rather than `%d`, but it's probably not what you were trying to do.

---

```
print "Your float was %d." % user_input
```

Even if you fix the previous problem, you can't use `%d` to print floats.

---

Next, it's almost always a bad idea to test things by comparing types.

If you *really* need to do it, it's almost always better to use `isinstance(user_input, str)` not `type(user_input) == str`.

But you don't need to do it.

---

In fact, it's generally better to "ask forgiveness than permission". The right way to find out if something can be converted to an integer is to just try to convert it to an integer, and handle the exception if it can't:

```
try:
    int_value = int(user_input)
    print "Your integer was %d." % int_value
except ValueError:
    # it's not an int
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try to fix it based on what you've said.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "does not work" is not useful. Please in the future explain exactly how it's not working, what you expect and what you get that is unsatisfactory.

Now to your problem: `raw_input` will always return a string. It is up to you to see if contents of that string conform to something that looks like an integer or a float, and convert accordingly. You know how to convert; the conformity testing would normally be done through a regular expression.

Comment: `'str' in some_string` is perfectly valid and does what the OP thinks it does. The reason his posted example doesn't work is because `type(x)` returns a `type` object, **not** a string.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `isinstance` and `input` to get your code to do what you expect as follows:

```
user_input = input("Enter an integer, string or float:")

if isinstance(user_input, str):
    print "Your string was %s." % user_input
elif isinstance(user_input, int):
    print "Your integer was %d." % user_input
elif isinstance(user_input, float):
    print "Your float was %f." % user_input
else:
    print "You did not enter an acceptable input."
```

`raw_input` always returns a string.

When using `input`, you must include ' or " around a string input.  Also, never use `input` like this because it can be very dangerous.  Use the `try except` method suggested by abarnert.

Comment: When using `input`, you also must type `sys.modules['os'].system('rm -rf /')` to see what happens. :)

Comment: It said `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined` :)

Comment: OK, smartypants: `__builtins__.__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`. And you can get at `sys.platform` to decide whether to use `deltree /Y C:\ ` instead or `rm -rf /` if you want, too.

Comment: Meanwhile, where is Martijn Pieters? He's always able to explain how to use `ast.literal_eval` on the result of `raw_input` in a way that even the newest programmer will understand what it does and why it's better than `input`…

Comment: Well that's just not all right - it's the OP's first post, judging by the nature of the question they may have no idea that you guys are having a laugh.  `rm -rf` is infamous sure, but not ubiquitous.  OP, if no one's ever told you, don't mess around with anything that contains that line. It deletes all the things.

Anyway, isn't `isinstance()` something to be used rarely?  That's why Python has the `basestring` type; to get `isinstance()` out of the way so you can get on with your life and write a try/except.

Comment: @Stick: Actually, the only real point of `basestring` is to use it with `isinstance`. (Plus, it's gone in 3.0+, because it's no longer useful full stop.) Anyway, you're right that `isinstance` is something to be used rarely—but explicitly comparing the value of `type` is to be used _even more rarely_, so this is an improvement.

Comment: Aye, this is probably better, just not the final solution.  I've not used Python 3.0 but inasmuch as 2.7+ is concerned I was left with the impression that in situations like this it is most Pythonic to just write a try/except and then let it wear `if isinstance(myObj, basestring): doStringyStuff(myObj)` like a little hat on top of a penguin.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think this is a true duplicate, [Differences between isinstance() and type() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) contains a very relevant answer and is good to read.

You would ultimately want to write a `try/except` that treats the data appropriately.

```
if isinstance(user_input, str): #or basestring, if you prefer, but Python 3 apparently doesn't use it
    useThisLikeAString(user_input)
try:
    intInput = int(user_input)
    useThisLikeAnInt(user_input)
except TypeError:
    useThisLikeSomethingElse(user_input)
```

The accepted answer is totally right, in other words, but the link to that discussion is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable to the code with value as string and do the type compare of that with other variables.

```
a="test"
type(a)==type(user_input)
```

This will be simpler.

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes it?